# Deriving from typing.Union with type arguments

Tags: python, python-typing

I am trying to derive a class from `typing.Union`, parametrized with type arguments, but I am getting a TypeError that I do not understand.

These all work fine:

```
import typing

class Foo(typing.Dict[str, int]): pass
class Bar(typing.Union[str]): pass
typing.Union[str, int]
```

(Of course, `Union[str]` is redundant and could just be `str`.)

But the following raises `TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given`:

```
class Foo(typing.Union[str, int]): pass
```

`class Foo(typing.Optional[str])` raises the same error, which makes sense since `typing.Optional[str]` is equivalent to `typing.Union[NoneType, str]`.

On the other hand, if there is some reason that subclassing `Union` is to be avoided whereas subclassing `Dict` or `List` is fine (I am vaguely modeling my code after [this portion of the Mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#defining-sub-classes-of-generic-classes)), I would like to know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union), you cannot subclass or instantiate a union.

```py
class Foo(typing.Union[str, int]):
    pass

def f(foo: Foo):
    print(foo)
    
f(1)
```

raises

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/typing.py", line 317, in __new__
    raise TypeError(f"Cannot subclass {cls!r}")
TypeError: Cannot subclass <class 'typing._SpecialForm'>
```

Instead, you can make a type alias:

```py
Foo = typing.Union[str, int]

def f(foo: Foo):
    print(foo)
    
f(1)
```

works as expected.

---

You may ask why

```
class Bar(typing.Union[str]):
    pass
```

is valid. If you look [at the source code](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/src/typing.py#L736) of `typing.Union` when its gets created (`__new__`), you'll see this snippet:

```py
if origin is Union:
    parameters = _remove_dups_flatten(parameters)
    # It's not a union if there's only one type left.
    if len(parameters) == 1:
        return parameters[0]
```

That means that, if a `typing.Union` has a single type, it will be equivalent to this type. In fact,

```py
print(isinstance(Bar(), str))
```

outputs true.

Comment: It appears that the behavior of Python has changed from 3.8 to 3.9 (which I am running). In 3.8 I also get the exception you report, but in 3.9 I get the (less helpful) `TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given`.